# Zencart zc_install/index.php page showing blank

Tags: zen-cart

I am trying to install reinstall zencart setup again on the following link:-

http://hobbystii.ro

But when i click to start the setup it shows a blank page. I am not able to understand the problem. Can please anyone help.

For my confirmation i deleted the database cleaned everything and tried reinstallation but same error showing blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rename the install directory "install" to start with; that is the original name if i remember correct. And try replacing the folder with original one from ZIP file.

However the best option would be to do a fresh install since your existing database will be wiped during an install either way. After doing so you can simply copy your theme files across or if you have customizations attempt copying the entire code from previous install across. Make sure to keep backups of everything and replace the configuration files for both admin and user side with that of the new one.